# How to search for a word between '' in SQL Table

Tags: sql

What I'm trying to do is to search for a word in SQL between two ' like 'test' but it won't work using:

```
SELECT id From TestTable WHERE Test LIKE '%'test'%'
```

Comment: can you show a sample table with some sample content?

Comment: @Ashutosh Yadav this is a example it's like having a table called "TestTable" and in it a column "Test" containing this data "this is a simple 'test'" in one of the rows

Comment: You need to use double apostrophs inside text constant - `'%''text''%'`.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL statement selects all id from TestTable Where the Test column has "test" in any position:

```sql
SELECT id From TestTable WHERE Test LIKE '%test%';
```

Let's say if the text in TestTable is this: `"this is a simple 'test'"`

and you are looking for `'test'` (not `test`) then your query will look like this:

```sql
SELECT id From TestTable WHERE Test LIKE "%'test'%";
```

As per my experience, sometimes outer quotes conflict with inner quotes. So I prefer To use different quotes for the outer and inner sides in like statement.

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle**
Here you can see the differences:

```sql
WITH
    a_tbl AS
        (
            Select 1 "ID", 'This is a test string 1' "TEST_STRING" From Dual Union ALL
            Select 2 "ID", 'This is a ''test'' string 2' "TEST_STRING" From Dual Union ALL
            Select 3 "ID", 'This is a "test" string 3' "TEST_STRING" From Dual Union ALL
            Select 4 "ID", 'This is a string 4 - without magic word' "TEST_STRING" From Dual Union ALL
            Select 5 "ID", 'This is a string 5 - just for testing' "TEST_STRING" From Dual 
        )
/*  Sample data
        ID TEST_STRING                           
---------- ---------------------------------------
         1 This is a test string 1                 
         2 This is a 'test' string 2               
         3 This is a "test" string 3               
         4 This is a string 4 - without magic word 
         5 This is a string 5 - just for testing  
*/


Select * From a_tbl Where TEST_STRING Like '%test%'
/*  Result
        ID TEST_STRING                           
---------- ---------------------------------------
         1 This is a test string 1                 
         2 This is a 'test' string 2               
         3 This is a "test" string 3               
         5 This is a string 5 - just for testing       
*/

Select * From a_tbl Where TEST_STRING Like '%''test''%'
/*  Result
        ID TEST_STRING                           
---------- ---------------------------------------
         2 This is a 'test' string 2             
*/

Select * From a_tbl Where TEST_STRING Like '%"test"%'
/*  Result
        ID TEST_STRING                           
---------- ---------------------------------------
         3 This is a "test" string 3             
*/
```

Note that **'%test%'** will select rows containing something like ***testing*** or ***testament*** and if you want just the word test then use surrounding spaces **LIKE '% test %'**